# Best way to implement authorization per group in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to find the best approach to authorize certain actions for a user based on the role they have in a group.
For instance Peter has admin role in group A so he can kick members in group A and member role in group B so he can only read content from group B.
[this is what model of user group relationship looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96mq7.png).
Is there a better way to implement authorization than loading group role in UserDetails like this:

```
(for (GroupUser groupuser: user.getGroupUsers()) {
   authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority('Group_'+groupuser.getId().getGroupId()+'_'+groupuser.getRole()));}
```

Comment: There is a small problem table desing. You created ROLE in relation table.
So it many to many relation why did you keep the role in relation table?

Comment: role refers to users role in a specific group not general role @Gurkanİlleez

Comment: In my humble opinion, How about grouping roles rather then grouping users. 
user can have multiple roles(authorizations) like read_b_content, read_a_content, write_a_content. When you kick the user from group, you can just remove authorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [ABAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-based_access_control) permission model which the security decision is not only determined by the user 's information , but also determined from the state/attribute of the protected resource too.

In term of spring security , it is best implemented using `@PreAuthorize` / `@PostAuthorize` / `@PostFilter` which allow you to use a SpEL expression to declaratively define the security logic which is an expression that will finally evaluate to true/false. In SpEL , you can access the input parameter and the return object of the method which performs that use-case that you want to apply security or even refer to a spring bean to call its method to do the evaluation.

For example, you could do something like :

```java
@PreAuthorize("@authzService.isAllowToKickMember(principal , #userToKick)")
public void kickMemeber(User userToKick){
    
}


@Service
public class AuthzService{

    public boolean isAllowToKickMember(User currentUser , User userToKick){
        //check if current user can kick a given user
    }
}
```

For pointers , please check out [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#el-access).

Comment: I like the answer. But if you are also hiding/showing sections on the page based on the same extra rules, then you will be executing the rules twice for the same request. And if the rules are expensive to execute, it can be a performance issue. So to avoid that, SecurityContext itself when created should have the role based permissions + attribute based permissions. (I have done that a while back in a project by executing the rules in a filter that creates the security context  but that project was not based on spring. )

Comment: Yes. The user object stored inside `SecurityContext` should contain as much as user information that is useful when determine the security decision. For the matter of executing twice , I am not sure if understand what you mean correctly. As I am writing a generic code, my backend API always need to validate the security even though the ui already check it because the backend api should be designed to be used by other client but not just the ui.

Comment: I missed this. I mean expression has to be evalauted, once before the `kickMemeber` method is invoked and once during the rendering of the template in the same instance of application. But if these rules are evaluated in a filter and added as dynamic privilege, then the rule is not run twice